# How can we get Source File revision number from pdb file?

Tags: winapi, windbg, pdb-files

We have source server enabled, and source indexing is implemented according [Using SrcSrv (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560147(v=vs.85).aspx). Debugger intelligently Copies the file from the server to the local cache. This works fine on developer machine.

Using IdebugSymbols Interface, we are able to retrieve information from pdb files. We have IdebugSymbols API functions for retrieving file name, source line number, module name etc.
Reference: [IDebugSymbols interface (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550856(v=vs.85).aspx)

My query is whether we can retrieve Source File revision number from .pdb file using some Microsoft API?

Please let me know if the problem is not understood or you require some more inputs from my side. Thanks :)

Comment: IDebugAdvanced2::GetSourceFileInformation() with DEBUG_SRCFILE_SYMBOL_TOKEN_SOURCE_COMMAND_WIDE looks somewhat promising.

Comment: Alright Hans, I'll try with this function and will get back to you soon. Thanks :)

Comment: @Xdev, you can give links a descriptive title, which makes the text more readable, see my edit.

Comment: @Thomas, Yes it looks readable now. I'll take care of that from now onwards. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one more general approach using Microsoft tools called "pdbstr.exe"and "Srctool.exe". These tools can be found at this location %PROGRAMFILES%\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\srcsrv
(from: [Source Server (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641(v=vs.85).aspx))

These tools simply interacts with pdb symbols file and fetches the information. So I was interested in fetching following info and yes that answers my question.
 - What are all files which are Indexed with their revision number?

Comment: I completely didn't know about that. Sorry for the misleading anwser.

Comment: @Lucas, No worries! your inputs led me to this conclusion. Thanks :)